# What do you call a variable, that is constant outside of a function, but variable inside?

Tags: javascript

I want to semantically seperate my variable types, like constants, private, public.

However I don't know the category name for variables that can only be changed inside a function, but are read-only outside a function:

F.ex:

```
function x() {
    var _private;
    var CONSTANT;
    this.public

    var privateCONSTANT; //I don't know what to call this....
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'privateCONSTANT',{
        get: function(){
            return privateCONSTANT;
        }
    });

}
```

What is a read-only private variable called?

Comment: Whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a read-only private variable called?

I'd call what you have there a "read-only public property" because:

1. It's a property, not a variable (from the external viewpoint; you're quite right that it's *backed* by a variable).
2. It's not a constant.
3. It is public.

If I wanted to emphasize that its value can change, I might call it a "read-only variable public property" but usually don't label things to that degree, I just document them.

The name for the variable that backs the property is usually something along the lines of "storage for ____", where ____ is the property name. I don't know a generic term for it other than "storage."